# OpenFile function open file ok but returns a NULL pointer (C program)

Tags: c, linux

I have had some troubles with my C code and decided to ask the gurus here what I am doing wrong.

```
//
// Routines.c
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

...

int OpenFile(FILE * fd, char * nm, char * md){
    FILE *rc; 
    printf("nm = %s, md = %s\n", nm, md);
    fd = fopen(nm, md);
    printf("fd fopen... errno = %d\n", errno);
    if ( fd == NULL ) {
        *rc = errno;
        printf("fopen %s -> rc = %d\n", nm, *rc);
        return rc;
    }
    printf("fd not NULL !!!\nrc = %d e errno = %d\n", *rc, errno);
    return 0;
}

...

int Generate (char * v) {
    int rc = 0;
    FILE *fd;

    rc = OpenFile (fd, v, "w");
    if ( rc ){
        printf ("open file error. RC = %d", rc);
        return rc;
    }
    if (fd == NULL){
        printf ("fd NULL !!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    CloseFile(fd);
    printf("Closed fd\n");

    printf("Leaving Generate. RC = %d\n",rc);
    return rc;
}

...
```

This Routines.c is made this way:

gcc -Wall -g -O0 -pedantic -fPIC -c Routines.c -o Routines.o

================================================================

```
//
// Caller.c
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Routines.h"

....

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ....
    char * v = "msgs.txt";

    ....

    Generate(v);

    ....

    return 0;
}
```

This Caller.c is made this way:

gcc -Wall -g -O0 -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -c Caller.c 
gcc -Wall -g -O0 -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -o Caller Caller.o Routines.o

================================================================

Both c files compile zero error (no warnings too).

-- Execution --

> msgs from OpenFile() (that is, the file has been opened correctly)

nm = msgs.txt, md = w
fd fopen... errno = 0
fd not NULL !!!
rc = 0 e errno = 0

> msgs from OpenFile() (What happen here ???)

fd NULL !!!

Someone can tell me what has happened with a file handler returned to Caller
as NULL, when it was correctly set on Routines at file opening ???

To solve my problem I had to do:

```
FILE * OpenFile(char * nm, char * md, int * rc){

fd = OpenFile (v, "w", &rc);
```

But I'd like to calm my mind down and understand what the hell i did to that happen.

Thanks (a lot) in advance.

Comment: `fd` is passed *by value*.

Answer (score 3):

`FILE * fd` in `OpenFile()` is a local variable containing a pointer to a file. You're changing the pointer inside your local function scope - none of that information gets out of your `OpenFile()` function.

Comment: Further to this observation I will point out that you *can* achieve what you're after but you need to pass in a File** (file pointer pointer), and then use *fd = fopen(...)